# remove unknown code in text using python

Tags: python, html, unicode

I saw unknown code like `\xe2\x80...` in the text, what exactly are these code? And how could I remove them from text in python?

Here's the text:

```
"Are you using bribery \xe2\x80\x94 or the less provocative \xe2\x80\x9crewards\xe2\x80\x9d \xe2\x80\x94 to push your girls to succeed this year?"
```

Comment: They represent UTF8 encoded characters. From my understanding you want to open a file, remove those UTF8 character and save the file?

Answer (score 0):

What you see as unknown codes is a `—` and quotation marks `“`. So these are normal characters encoded in utf-8. If you really want to remove them:

```
text_without_unicode_chrs = ''.join(ch for ch in text if ch<'\x80')
```

Comment: Looks a bit ugly, why not `text.decode("ascii", errors="ignore")`?