# python "-" dash showing as "\xe2\x80\x94" - how to correct

Tags: python

I am reading in a file and I read in this line something like `for line in f:`

```
Please Please Me,22 March 1963,Parlophone(UK),1,—,Gold,Platinum
```

I then do a

```
b=line.split(",")
print b
```

and it gives me this:

`['Please Please Me', '22 March 1963', 'Parlophone(UK)', '1', '\xe2\x80\x94', 'Gold', 'Platinum\n']`

I want `—` and not `\xe2\x80\x94`.

What exactly is happening here and how do I overcome it?

**Edit1** the problem is when iput it in an array it seems. python 2.7.5 on windows7

```
$ cat test.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


b = "Please Please Me,22 March 1963,Parlophone(UK),1,—,Gold,Platinum"

for i in b.split(','):

    print i.decode('utf-8')

c = b.split(',')

print c
```

output:

```
$ python test.py
Please Please Me
22 March 1963
Parlophone(UK)
1
—
Gold
Platinum
['Please Please Me', '22 March 1963', 'Parlophone(UK)', '1', '\xe2\x80\x94', 'Gold', 'Platinum']
```

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819962/remove-unknown-code-in-text-using-python

Comment: Do you want to use a single-byte ASCII dash? That is to say, is the problem that it's the wrong kind of dash compared to the one you want to use, or that it's the kind of dash you want to use, but repr() doesn't render it to one character?

Comment: my understaning is that it's the kind of dash I want to use, but repr() doesn't render it to one character. it gives me this `\xe2\x80\x94`

Answer (score 2):

That is probably unicode

Try adding the utf line at the top of your script (under the  #!/usr/bin/python3)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Comment: could not get this to work, Python 2.7.5
 on windows7

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to `Python3`.

Demo:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> line = 'Please Please Me,22 March 1963,Parlophone(UK),1,—,Gold,Platinum'
>>> line.split(',')
['Please Please Me', '22 March 1963', 'Parlophone(UK)', '1', '—', 'Gold', 'Platinum']
```

Answer (score 1):

@[Irshad Bhat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4154185/irshad-bhat)

Upgrading to python 3 didnt help me in my use case , was Still facing the same issue . 
 But i found a [solution](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-February/067414.html) , This solution was Quite effective ,and hope it helped others who are parsing documents like me.
Link to Solution: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2009-February/067414.html

EDIT:
A short function , inspired from above link

```
def clean_text(text):
    unwanted_char = '\x00\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06\x07\x08\t\n\x0b\x0c\r\x0e\x0f\x10\x11\x12\x13\x14\x15\x16\x17\x18\x19\x1a\x1b\x1c\x1d\x1e\x1f\x7f\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff'
    text = "".join([(" " if n in unwanted_char else n) for n in text if n not in unwanted_char])
    return text
```

Please Check the indentation and apply in your code

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as expected.

`print i.decode('utf-8')` decodes each String form UTF-8 to 8bit ascii (ISO-8859-1). The dash in the example is not a normal dash, it's [Em-dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm)

Em-dash is **not in** the 8bit ascii character set. Therefore `decode()` can't decode it to a regular character and replaces it with python source code representation for the UTF-8 character (`\xe2\x80\x94`).

If you want to show a dash instead, you should replace the Em-dash with a regular dash before running `decode()`.

```
for i in b.split(','):

    i.replace(u'—', '-')
    print i.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


b = "Please Please Me,22 March 1963,Parlophone(UK),1,—,Gold,Platinum"


for i in b.split(','):

    print i.decode('utf-8')
```

Windows 7 / Python 2.7

Comment: ```$ cat test.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


b = "Please Please Me,22 March 1963,Parlophone(UK),1,—,Gold,Platinum"

for i in b.split(','):

    print i.decode('utf-8')

c = b.split(',')

print c

$ python test.py
Please Please Me
22 March 1963
Parlophone(UK)
1
—
Gold
Platinum
['Please Please Me', '22 March 1963', 'Parlophone(UK)', '1', '\xe2\x80\x94', 'Gold', 'Platinum']``` the problem is when I put `-` in an array, it seems

Comment: I ran this code on windows. It decoded **\xe2\x80\x94** as **\x97**. I am not sure what exactly is happening in the background but this code does work on windows.

Answer (score -2):

`'\xe2\x80\x94'` denotes hyphen(-).

This is what you get when you print the list.

```
for a in ['Please Please Me', '22 March 1963', 'Parlophone(UK)', '1', '\xe2\x80\x94',   'Gold', 'Platinum\n']:  
    print a
```

```
Please Please Me  
22 March 1963  
Parlophone(UK)  
1  
—  
Gold  
Platinum
```

You can replace the `'\xe2\x80\x94'` with `''`.